# How to access the request url in the validate method of the http strategy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, passport.js, nestjs

I want to access the context object that exists in guards, inside my bearer strategy validate method. Can I pass it as an argument alongside with the token?

bearer-auth.guard.ts:

```js
@Injectable()
export class BearerAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('bearer') {
    canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
        return super.canActivate(context);
    }
}
```

http.strategy.ts:

```js
@Injectable()
export class HttpStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
    constructor(private globalService: GlobalService) {
        super();
    }

    async validate(token: string) {
        const customer = await this.globalService.validateCustomer(token);
        if (!customer) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
        }
        return customer;
    }
}
```

I want something like this:

```js
async validate(token: string, context) { // <-- context object as argument
    const customer = await this.globalService.validateCustomer(token);
    if (!customer) {
        throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    return customer;
}
```

Comment: What do you need the context for? The `request`?

Comment: @KimKern Yes, I need the url

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can access the `request` object by passing the option `passReqToCallback: true` to `passport-http-bearer`. Then the first parameter in your validate callback will be the `request`:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {
    // Add the option here
    super({ passReqToCallback: true });
  }

  async validate(request: Request, token: string) {
    // Now you have access to the request url
    console.log(request.url);
    const user = await this.authService.validateUser(token);
    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

See a running demo here

[image: Edit Nest HTTP Auth]